# method to override to provide instances of my PFObject sublcasses for PFQuery

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is there a method on PFObject that I can override so that I handle creating instances of my PFObject subclasses returned by the sdk, say the results of a PFQuery?

I've tried it out and the methods I've overridden from PFObject, PFObject+PFSubclassing, don't get called when PFQuery creates instances of MY OWN Class. I mean, what's up with that? They seem to have gone to some length to let me provide PFObject subclasses and they don't let me provide the instances for my own class?

one method

```
+(instancetype)objectWithoutDataWithClassName:(NSString *)className
                                      objectId:(NSString *)objectId;
```

gets called but on PFOBject not on the my PFObject subclass.

Comment: Did you register your subclasses?

Comment: yes, I did. in the +[MySubclass load] method.